# How to add/assign Types Dinamically to typescript type object?

Tags: typescript, types

I have an type which can be some predefined primitive string

```
type Definition = "foo" | "bar";
```

This cases are function names, which can be called by user.

Users can add their own functions as well, so type `Definition` should add new case.

```
addFunction('baz', () => console.log('test'));

// Now definitions should be: "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
```

I have tried these:
Variant 1:

```
type Definition = "foo" | "bar" | string;

type ExtendedDefinition = "foo" | "bar" | string; 
// In this case vscode doesn't give me autocomplete
```

Variant 2:

```
type Definition = "foo" | "bar";
// doesn't give definitions as well
```

That type, `Definition` is key for my package, I use that functions almost in every function.

How can Implement this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create something people started calling a *loose autocomplete type* with the [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type like so:

```
type ExtendedDefinition = "foo" | "bar" | Omit<string, "foo" | "bar">;

const arg: ExtendedDefinition = "anything"; // -> no compilation error
```

This will still give you autocompletion for the string union (`"foo" | "bar"`) but also allows `arg` to have any string assigned.

You can even build your own custom utility type `LooseAutocomplete` based on this pattern:

```
type Definition = "foo" | "bar";
type LooseAutocomplete<T extends string> = T | Omit<string, T>;

const arg: LooseAutocomplete<Definition> = "anything";
```

---

`type Definition = "foo" | "bar" | string;` does not work because the compiler infers both `"foo"` and `"bar"` as `string`s and breaks the whole union down to a `string` which won't give you autocomplition of course. Now what the `Omit` does is removing this exact union of values from the `string` type. Hence the compiler treats the union and the type `string` seperately.

Comment: Thank you. Autocompletion works good, but what about extension? I am creating package, where user can add new function and then give autocompletion of that functions

Comment: As far is I understand what you're trying to do, extending your type at runtime is impossible.